# Como cambiar el select option a checkbox de un campo bit en mvc entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Resulta que estoy creando un proyecto donde requiero utilizar checkbox, cree los controladores y vistas con scaffolding de entity framework, pero al ver la vista create me aparece un select option en ves de un checkbox, puesto que en mi base de datos tengo registros con campo bit. Quisiera fueran tan amables de ayudarme soy novato en MVC.

En la vista create:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dolor_Abdominal, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dolor_Abdominal)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dolor_Abdominal, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

En mi vista aparece:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en mi Base de Datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No hay mejor forma de contarnos lo que hiciste que incluyendo tu código en la pregunta

Comment: Ya lo edite, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando en ASP.NET MVC creas las Vistas mediante **scaffolding**, normalmente se auto-generan los **Html Helpers** (**`@Html`**) adecuados para cada propiedad del Modelo de datos que utilices.

Pero existen casos como el tuyo (campos bit y otros), donde **no está del todo claro** para el scaffolding, cual es el control HTML que se debe **renderizar** para ese tipo de dato.

Es por esto que se deja la responsabilidad de crear el **control adecuado**, al **motor de Vistas** (Razor) mediante el Helper **`@Html.EditorFor()`**.

Lo que debes hacer si quieres que se cree un control del tipo checkbox, es **indicarlo tu mismo** mediante un **`@Html.CheckBoxFor()`**:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Dolor_Abdominal)
```

Comment: Hola Amigo logre editar de la siguiente forma: `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Dolor_Abdominal.Value)`, pero al momento de guardar un dato en la base de datos me aparace "null" y en la aplicación en la lista me aparece "Sin establecer". Podrías ayudarme.

Comment: @SELSOALONSO: Varias cosas. Indica en la pregunta el Modelo de la Vista, y de que tipo es la propiedad `Dolor_Abdominal`. Por qué estableces `model => model.Dolor_Abdominal.Value` con `.Value`?. Por otra parte, si el problema lo tienes a insertar en la BD, **ya no está relacionado con la pregunta**. Te está llegando el valor de `Dolor_Abdominal` al Controlador?

Comment: Agregue .Value porque me indica un error donde no se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo bool a bool, en Razor. En mi modelo aparace: `public Nullable<bool> Dolor_Abdominal { get; set; }`

Comment: @SELSOALONSO: Claro, es una propiedad `Nullable` puede se TRUE, FALSE o NULL. Mira a ver que valor estás insertando en la BD. Y otra cosa, Por qué necesitas que la propiedad pueda ser NULL?, no te vale con TRUE o FALSE?

Comment: Si lo que necesito es que la propiedad sea TRUE o FALSE, pero el scaffolding lo generó automaticamente como `Nullable`, te comente que en la base de datos tengo un campo `bit` puesto que es el equivalente a bool, no entiendo el porque de esta situación.

Comment: @SELSOALONSO: Pues quita el `Nullable` del Modelo: `public bool Dolor_Abdominal { get; set; }`

Comment: Encontré la solución resulta que tenía que cambiar en mi base de datos "Allow Nulls" en mis tablas con campos `bit`, asi al generar las tablas con scaffolding en mi modelo ya no aparecerá `Nullable`, con esto y con la corrección que me enviaste del `EditorFor` a `CheckBoxFor` solucione el inconveniente. Muchas Gracias.